# importing my database into heroku database

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres

i am trying to import database into heroku .

i am creating an app into heroku but its not access by database after migration
what can i do?

```
 heroku pg:psql --app YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE < updates.sql

 heroku pgbackups:restore YOUR_STAGING_DATABASE_NAME `heroku pgbackups:url -
 -app YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME` --app YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME --confirm  
   YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME

 heroku pg:backups restore `heroku pg:backups public-url -a   
   YOUR_PRODUCTION_APP_NAME` YOUR_STAGING_DATABASE_NAME --app   
   YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME --confirm YOUR_STAGING_APP_NAME

 pg_dump -U USERNAME DATABASE --no-owner --no-acl -f backup.sql 

 heroku pg:psql --app APPNAME < backup.sql 

 heroku pg:reset --app APPNAME HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE
```

i had tried but failled what can i do?
i want to import database from my local postgres to heroku app

Comment: You need to upload your database file to somewhere then use command: `heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL` to import your database. You should use `dump` format instead of `sql`.

Comment: i am trying this  commands heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/db_IndusryPrime.dump'F:\ROR\industryprime\industryprime   its not working

Comment: Please make sure you get the right link to the dump file, you can try to pass the link in browser to see if it is correct.

Comment: i have an error this releted this question i.e.,when check by command heroku pg:psql its showing an error C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)

Comment: This solution may be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490